# How to judge the platform is Android or Iphone or the others for a website?

Tags: android, iphone, web, responsive-design

I want to run different kind of javascript according to the platform.
So how can I use javascript to judge the platform?

Comment: I suggest you don't use this kind of detection unless you absolutely need to.  Instead detect if the browser supports a particular feature you need it to support.  Android has many browsers Default, Chrome, Firefox etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For detect android try:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; //&& ua.indexOf("mobile");
if(isAndroid) {
    // Do something!
    // Redirect to Android-site?
    window.location = 'http://android.davidwalsh.name';
}
```

For iOS try this question:[Detect iOS version less than 5 with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8348139/1548523)