# Detect iOS 5 or Higher with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, user-agent

I'm trying to use the following script to detect whether the browser is iOS 5 or higher (from this SO thread [Detect iOS version less than 5 with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348139/detect-ios-version-less-than-5-with-javascript)).

```
function iOSversion() {
    if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
        var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
        return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
    }
}

ver = iOSversion();

if (ver[0] >= 5) {
    alert('This is running iOS 5 or later.');
} else {
    alert('This is NOT running iOS 5 or later.');
}
```

It works in iOS 5 or later as it should, but in any other browser it produces the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

And then all JavaScript below this script fails.

Please can someone advise how I can fix this?? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're checking if `ver[0] >= 5`, but if it's not iOS, `ver` is undefined, so you have to check if it's defined first :

```
function iOSversion() {
    if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
        var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
        return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
    }
}

var ver = iOSversion();

if (ver && ver[0] >= 5) {
    alert('This is running iOS 5 or later.');
} else {
    alert('This is NOT running iOS 5 or later.');
}
```

Comment: May be a better idea to `typeof ver != 'undefined'` instead of rely on `if (ver)`

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I knew it was something simple I was missing. I'm using this to apply position: fixed to mobile browsers that can handle it. UA sniffing is necessary over feature detection in this case as most mobile browsers support fixed position but many in a very buggy way. Thanks again for the speedy answer.

Answer (score 0):

`iOSversion()` returns `undefined` for any other browser.

Trying to do: `undefined[0]` will give you the error that you got.

You can change your check to:

```
if (ver !== undefined && ver[0] >= 5) {
    // ..
}
```