# Detect iOS Version

Tags: javascript, ios, user-agent

I am currently using the below code to check what version of iOS the user is running however it has a small problem, if there is a 3rd digit to the version it doesn't add a period to it, so when I check it on a device running iOS 9.0.1 it returns 9.01, I haven't been able to figure out how to fix the below to add a period between the second and third digit. any help is appreciated :)

```
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Detect</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(){

var iOS = parseFloat(
    ('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1])
    .replace('undefined', '3_2').replace('_', '.').replace('_', '')
) || false;

 alert(iOS)

 }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you need to know the exact version?

Comment: Ill be serving content based on the users iOS Version, the exact version is important for defining the content that they get

Comment: What do you mean by "content"? Can't you use feature detection instead?

Comment: its jailbreak related content and is firmware specific

Answer (score 4):

You can use JQuery mentioned by this guy. Which works for my iOS 10 Beta. 
https://codepen.io/niggi/pen/DtIfy

Otherwise you can try this

```
function iOSVersion() {
  if(window.MSStream){
    // There is some iOS in Windows Phone...
    // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx
    return false;
  }
  var match = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/),
      version;

  if (match !== undefined && match !== null) {
    version = [
      parseInt(match[1], 10),
      parseInt(match[2], 10),
      parseInt(match[3] || 0, 10)
    ];
    return parseFloat(version.join('.'));
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this guys post worked for me

[Detect iOS version less than 5 with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348139/detect-ios-version-less-than-5-with-javascript)

from Peter T Bosse II

also props for using pure javascript here.